# I want to add multiple small images of solar panel inside polygon on google maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-maps, polygon

[here is the image of polygon and I want to add multiple images of solar panel inside the polygon][1]

I want to add multiple small images of solar panel inside polygon on google maps I am using `@react-google-maps/api package`

```
import React from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  DrawingManager,
  LoadScript,
  Polygon,
  OverlayView,
  GroundOverlay,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { setRoofSurface } from "../../Features/RoofArea/roofarea.actions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import solar from "../../assest/images/solar.jpg";

export function AreaMap({ coords }) {
  const {
    OfferEditionCustomer: {
      singleCustomer: { location },
    },
  } = useSelector((state) => state);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const containerStyle = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "60%",
  };
  const drawingOnLoad = (drawingManager) => {
    console.log(drawingManager);
  };
  const onPolygonComplete = (polygon) => {
    var area = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(
      polygon.getPath()
    );
    console.log(polygon.getPoints());
    const latlng = polygon.latLngs.Rd[0].Rd.map((item) => {
      return {
        lat: item.lat(),
        lng: item.lng(),
      };
    });

    console.log(polygon.latLngs, "polygon");

    if (latlng)
      dispatch(
        setRoofSurface({ name: "coords", value: JSON.stringify(latlng) })
      );

    dispatch(setRoofSurface({ name: "area", value: area }));
  };

  const center = {
    lat: 40.74,
    lng: -74.18,
  };

  const bounds = {
    north: 1.773941,
    south: 40.712216,
    east: -74.12544,
    west: -74.22655,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LoadScript
        id="script-loader"
        googleMapsApiKey=""
        language={"en"}
        region={"EN"}
        version={"weekly"}
        loadingElement={
          <div
            style={{
              minWidth: "100%",
              minHeight: "50vh",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              display: "flex",
            }}
          >
            <CircularProgress />
          </div>
        }
        libraries={["drawing,geometry"]}
      >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={location && JSON.parse(location).latlang}
          zoom={20}
          mapTypeId="satellite"
        >
          <DrawingManager
            onLoad={drawingOnLoad}
            onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
            options={{
              drawingControl: true,
              drawingControlOptions: {
                position: 2,
                drawingModes: ["polygon"],
              },
            }}
          />
          <Polygon
            draggable={true}
            editable={true}
            options={{
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: "#FF0000",
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
            }}
            paths={coords && JSON.parse(coords)}
          />

          {/* <OverlayView
            center={location && JSON.parse(location).latlang}
            mapPaneName={OverlayView.MAP_PANE}
          >
            <div style={{ display: "grid" }}>
              {Array(20)
                .fill()
                .map(() => {
                  return (
                    <img
                      src={solar}
                      style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px" }}
                    />
                  );
                })}
            </div>
          </OverlayView> */}
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "here is the image" nope, please edit question if you really wish to show the image OR remove that.  I removed the repeated text from the bottom that was already at the top

Comment: "Cannot use import statement outside a module" as it stands in your question now

Answer (score 0):

Here we do following.

1.Add a polygon

2.Get the polygon coordinates.

3.Now draw a icon with the marker in the specified coordinates

4.Then it will look like an icon inside the polygon

So here, after adds the polygon, drawn icon with the help of marker in the center place of the polygon.

```
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, center;
            for (i = 0; i < polygonsCoordinates.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(polygonsCoordinates[i]);
            }
            center = bounds.getCenter();
            var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
            var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: center.lat(), lng: center.lng() },
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
```

so like this you can add multiple markers.
hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: thank got you reply . i have implemented your solution but on;y shows single image and its getting out of the polygon bounds . I have to multiple images according to size of polygon and that they dont have to overflow the polygon